# Minor bug in Your Community Section

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-norepro, communities-list

When select any community and then click more than once quickly, the community added multiple times. However, it does not allow me to save this settings. It gives the error **"something bad happened, Please try again."**
The following screenshot shows the problem. I have selected **Stack Apps** and clicked on the Add button twice.

[image]

Error when I try to save this. "something bad happened, Please try again."

[image]

Another issue I have got is in search Community. It is a design issue. I don't know how but suddenly when I am trying to search community the dropdown list displays at the top of the window.

[image]

Comment: You are very fast with clicking. :-) I´m not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Yaa reproduced, it added twice on double click

Comment: another problem in search community drop down list. the list shows to of the penal instead of at the bottom of search bar.

Comment: nice observation.:)

Comment: Heh. Yeah, we don't allow duplicates in the list, so that explains the first issue you're seeing. I'll see about fixing all this up this week.

Comment: Thanks @AnnaLear for editing my question and replying me.

Comment: Please don't edit with new bugs, start new question tagged bug to  report new bugs. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, Now, I have edited my question and posted a new [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225252/252964).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the first issue with adding duplicates. The fix will go live in the next build.

However, I can't reproduce the other issue you're seeing. If you have any more information that might help narrow down the scenario there, that'd be helpful.

Comment: @Nimesh Out of curiosity, what's your browser/OS?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m and OS is Windows XP SP2.

Comment: I have also checked that second issue(Community Search Popup List) and I have noticed that this problem occurs only when list popped up over the Community Search Box. When I type text in the search box the Popup Panel Size get reduced from the bottom. But, top location does not get changed.