# Deleted or Added Item does not get affected after save in Community Section

Tags: bug, status-norepro, communities-list

Previously I have posted a bug related to duplication selection community section. Anna Lear has corrected that issue. Now I got another issue in Add/Delete item.

When I try to delete any item. It gets deleted. I did not get any problem. But, after save the deleted item still shows in the list. It only removed after refreshing page. This happens also when I add a new item.

-Stack Overflow community has deleted from the list.
[image]

-After save community settings still Stack Overflow shows in the list.
[image]

I have noticed that some time it does not give any bug on add/remove item from community list. but, if you try to add and remove multiple time it happens.

**EDITED:**
You can download and see the video. [How to reproduce this bug?](http://www.dantainfosoft.a78.org/so_bug.rar). The file is compressed in rar file.

Comment: I can reproduce that. There´s something buggy going on here. I have to reload the page each time I make an edit

Comment: I cannot reproduce this... the list is updating for me right away without needing to refresh.

Comment: Some time this not happens. When you do this multiple time then you can see something wrong in it. Try this way delete an item then save it then again add that item and save it. repeating this step 2 or 3 times then the problem you will see.

Comment: @AnnaLear I have uploaded a video that demonstrate how to reproduce that issue. I have edited my question. You can download video from the given link.

Comment: @Anna can you reproduce now?

Comment: Tagging this one as norepro, since that's what it was back in the day. The [recent regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230976/editing-the-your-communities-list-does-not-reflect-changes-after-clicking-sav) is a new issue, not the same as reported here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing all "my communities" causing the list to reset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224093/removing-all-my-communities-causing-the-list-to-reset)