# Editing the "Your communities" list does not reflect changes after clicking "Save"

Tags: bug, status-completed, communities-list

When adding/removing sites from "Your communities", the changes appear while editing, and are still present when clicking "edit" again, but are not visible after clicking "save". It takes a page reload to update the dropdown.

Comment: Hmm...no repro on Chrome 34...

Comment: ... And now I can't reproduce it either. What's the recommended "close" action on Meta?

Comment: You should be able to delete it, but you've got a couple upvotes; maybe others have reproduced it? Bugs are sometimes hard to reproduce...Might be useful to wait for an official [tag:status-norepro] edit or any other responses before deleting if you think the bug is worth ferreting out. Seems a little trivial to me, FWIW, especially if it's only intermittently manifest and reloading works around it, but I don't see any harm in leaving it open regardless (not that I could be trusted to if there were such potential).

Comment: I thought this was by design. Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242684/immediately-update-my-community-list-when-i-change-it

Answer (score 2):

The answer here was (predictably) caching.

We cache the list of favorite sites in Redis, and when a user saves a new version of that list, we clear the cache. A change went out a few months ago that made the cache fetch prefer slave Redis instances over master, which basically means that the clear directive didn't have a chance to propagate before we attempted to re-fetch and re-cache the updated list.

A fix for this will be going out with the next production build.