# Immediately update my community list when i change it

Tags: bug, communities-list

If i add a site to my community list (accessible by clicking the SE icon in the top left), i usually want to be able to get to it. Right away. But with the current setup, once i click 'save' to keep it there, it disappears, as the old list is shown. I can't see the new site i put there (or removed, or reordered) until i reload the page.

Could it just do a quick recalculation of the site list when i modify it? It doesn't even need to give me my rep on it - just a simple link.

Comment: It *should* show you the updated list, if I recall. I'll take a look.

Comment: It didn't when i added Code Golf this morning.

Comment: Yup, reproduced just now.

Comment: @Anna the response from http://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/site-switcher/save-pinned-sites does not contain the newly added site.

Comment: Huh, so it is broken. Might be a regression. Call it a bug, I'll fix.